# A runtime error when using NSMutableString

Tags: swift, nsmutablestring

```
let address = "http://www.example.com/?cevent=imt%2Fguide%252525252525252F"
let address2 = "http://www.example.com/?cevent=imt%2Fguide%2525252525252521"
let bodyString=NSMutableString()

bodyString.appendFormat("\(address)")
```

when I test in playground, the code errors, but when I use

```
bodyString.appendFormat("\(address2)")
```

it works! Why?

[The runtime error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L35mh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `appendFormat` but you're not using any formatter string.

It should be used like this, with a formatter as the first argument (here the normal text formatter):

```
bodyString.appendFormat("%@", address)
```